# Tagging topics by User Experience Level

Tags: feature-request

Inspired by this question [Handling introductory questions](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85/handling-introductory-questions?rq=1), I am wondering if it will be any useful at all to have a way to tag or mark questions by Experience/Knowledge level, or to another extend a way for a user to denote his experience with Joomla when asking a question.

So for example, while I don't know what SE system is able to provide, there could be questions marked/filtered with tags like: Beginner, Intermediate, Advanced, or Joomla Basics.

Then it could be a way to filter questions in the list to show only these questions etc.

Maybe these tags shouldn't be of the same kind like the tags that are present in the system.

I don't have an exact suggestion about this - these are some core thoughts for discussion or a possible feature.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I actually like the idea of this, however the problem is that, with active users, we kind of get an idea of their level (which is fine), so this would be more aimed at new users, who won't be aware about specifying their Joomla knowledge level.

If the tags are created for them to use, how will they know that they're available to be used?

Comment: I totally agree with you. In my mind what it could make this work better is if in the question submission form, there would be another (new one) field - something like a dropdown, with title: "Joomla Level" and select options the levels. However SE doesn't provide this, so that could be a possible feature request, if we could compile it to a more thorough feature suggestion. Think that a such feature could work like a categorization feature in addition to the current tags system. Just thoughts...

Comment: That would be a good feature. You could possibly ask on Stack Exchange meta. I have the feeling they will say no, as all beta systems are exactly the same, so changing 1 may be too much effort, but definitely worth a shot ;)